# Any idea why I am getting "Fatal Error: Execution time limit was exceeded" on .NET fiddle for this code?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to run a simple test

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{

    public static Task DelayAndThenPrint(int mills)
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(mills);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Delayed {0} milliseconds and then reached here", mills));                          
        });
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        { 
            await DelayAndThenPrint(200);
            Console.WriteLine("hey!");
            await DelayAndThenPrint(100);
        }).Wait();  
    }
}
```

and am getting the error

> Fatal Error: Execution time limit was exceeded

Any idea why?

Comment: Depending on how they configure the world for asynchronous code, you may be deadlocking and thus hit the 5 second limit.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a couple of things wrong:

- `Task.Delay(mills)` does *not* delay; it returns a `Task` that will delay.  You need to wait for that task to complete to actually get the delay.  Currently you will experience almost zero delay.
- `new Task()` is one of the few ways to create a *cold* `Task`.  I.e. it is not running.  When you await a cold task, it will wait until the task completes or throws; i.e. forever.  Why it doesn't start it must have been a design decision, but the IL generated; e.g [here](http://www.filipekberg.se/2013/01/16/what-does-async-await-generate/) appears to confirm it.  You need to start the task first with `.Start()`, or instead of returning `new Task()`, use `Task.Run()` to create a *hot* (already running) task.

Better still, reduce your method to this:

```
public static async Task DelayAndThenPrint(int mills)
{
    await Task.Delay(mills).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Delayed {0} milliseconds and then reached here", mills));                          
}
```

Comment: Everyone [should really never use the task constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the Sandbox limitations of .Net Fiddle
Currently the Sandbox has the following limits per single run:

- Code Block Size - 100K
- Console Output Size -100K
- Execution Time - 5s
- Memory - 10MB
- Disk Space - 1MB

([Source](https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/282670-restrictions))

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [sellotape's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091989/209259) which is spot on, you aren't using await/async correctly.  `DelayAndThenPrint` isn't async so await it really doesn't do anything.  What you're looking for is:

```
public static async Task DelayAndThenPrint(int mills)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(mills);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Delayed {0} milliseconds and then reached here", mills));                          
    });
}

public static void Main()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    { 
        await DelayAndThenPrint(200);
        Console.WriteLine("hey!");
        await DelayAndThenPrint(100);
    }).Wait();  
}
```